# Background Color - breakpoint for mobile

Tags: css

Trying to help for a page - https://example.com/.   If I scale my desktop browser - smaller like I'm trying to view as a tablet/phone ..the header has a red background...

How can I make the full desktop version of the header have the - same -background that the mobile page has?

I'm not familiar with this template at all and can't find what causes it to switch background colors

Comment: Welcome to Webmasters! Unfortunately, we cannot do trouble shooting of a site. The format of this site is designed for specific questions and answers that provide targeted solutions. Are you familiar with CSS? If not, you can start here to begin understanding CSS. https://www.w3schools.com/css/ If you have specific questions, please do ask them. We are here to help. Cheers!!